# Get user-locked client.ovpn from openvpn admin

Tags: linux, openvpn

I am still newish to managing Openvpn. My question is trying to find how/where I can download the client.ovpn files for linux users. When I go to the admin interface, I can't seem to find it. There is a link for each platform and how to install and set it up. I am able to download the openvpn client for other platforms like mac, which seems to have it baked in. At least all you need to do in order to connect is just put in your password.

However I am looking for the client.ovpn file so that I can use it for the Linux client. There is a link on the admin log in page which gives you instructions on how to set it up. Though it just says "Download the client.ovpn", but not from where. Looking around the internet some people show that there is a user-locked file on their admin login page. But I don't have this. Is there something I forgot to turn on?

Answer (score 0):

It should be displayed right after you login to the user interface, not on the admin interface.

[image: screen shot of openvpn post user login screen]

Comment: Also, under admin -> "Client Settings"  There are a bunch of check boxes to customize the Client Web Server UI, including "Offer user-locked profile"

Comment: Thank you for your advice @Fitz. It was not displayed right after login in the UI like I thought either. That is why I was asking. Though I did miss the "Client Settings", user-locked profile was on, but server-locked profile was not.
After some more searching and reading through documents what I ended up doing was ssh'ing in to the server and running `sudo /usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli --user $USER GetUserlogin >client.ovpn` to populate it. This helped me out https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/create-connection-profiles-and-connect-client-installers/